# Probability to find A

Tags: probability

all. I think I need some help:

Suppose the answer of all questions were A.
If you are smart, the probability to find A is 0.001.
If you are not smart, the probability is only 0.00001.
And the probability to be smart is 0.3.

1. What is the probability to find A?
2. What is the probability that you are smart
   a) if you find A?
   b) if you not find A?

In the first task is it just 0.001*0.00001=0.00000001?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you've tried? Have you studied conditional probability?

Comment: The answers to all three questions are A, axiomatically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe draw a tree diagram. There are two branches, Smart and Not Smart. The branch Smart has $0.3$ written beside it, the branch Not Smart has 0.7$ written beside it.

From Smart, there are two branches, Find A and Not Find A. The Find A branch has $0.001$ written beside it. There are similarly two branches leading from Not Smart.

The probability of finding A is the sum of the probabilities over all paths that lead to Find A. The required probability is $(0.3)(0.001)+(0.7)(0.00001)$.

We can also derive the answer using conditional probability notation. Write $S$ for Smart, $S'$ for Not Smart, $A$ for Find A.

We want $\Pr(A)$. This is $\Pr(A|S)\Pr(S)+\Pr(A|S')\Pr(S')$. All the required components are known.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the probability of being smart is $0.3$ and the probability of finding $A$ if you're smart is $0.001,$ so the probability of being smart and finding $A$ is $0.3\cdot0.001=0.0003.$ Now, what is the probability of *not* being smart? Hence, what is the probability of finding $A$ and *not* being smart? Hence, what is the probability of finding $A$?

For part $2$, we will use the answers to part $1$. If the probability of finding $A$ is $p,$ then the probability of being smart if you find $A$ is $\frac{0.0003}p.$ Now, the probability of being smart and *not* finding $A$ is $0.001-0.0003=0.0007,$ and the probability of not finding $A$ is $1-p.$ Hence, the probability of being smart if you don't find $A$ is $\frac{0.0007}{1-p}.$